# PHP: Convert timezone of a timestamp

Tags: php, zend-framework, timezone, timestamp

I have issues converting a timestamp, which is a UTC datetime, to another timezone using Zend Framework. My default timezone is Europe/Paris

```
$timestamp = 1319530421;
$date = new Zend_Date();
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
$date->set($timestamp, Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::W3C).' - '.$date->getTimezone().'<br />';
$date->setTimezone('Europe/Paris');
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::W3C).' - '.$date->getTimezone().'<br />';
```

which echoes

```
2011-10-25T08:13:41+00:00 - UTC
2011-10-25T10:13:41+02:00 - Europe/Paris
```

but it's wrong because that timestamp is

```
2011-10-25T10:13:41+00:00 - UTC
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question please. I dont understand what you think is wrong about the output. Also, is there any particular reason for using the slow and cumbersome Zend_Date API. What features are you using that the native DateTime API doesnt offer?

Comment: I work with timestamps. Those who are stored in database are in UTC. I just want to convert them to user's timezone. By the other side, I don't have to do it with Zend_Date. I'm just using zend framework. A PHP solution is valid for me.

Comment: but what is wrong with the dates? 1319530421 really is 2011-10-25T08:13:41 GMT/UTC. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/HxJgeJ or try with http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Then, I think I have a bug parsing dates. My bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem :) and do yourself a favor and try the native DateTime API.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong about the timestamp in your example. It's date is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$timestamp = 1319530421;

echo date('c e', $timestamp); # 2011-10-25T08:13:41+00:00 UTC
```

So it's all correct with your example, just your expectation isn't.